# How to force Internet Explorer to use the native Citrix Receiver and not Java version

Tags: remote-desktop, java, citrix, citrix-receiver

My Java Citrix client seemed to be working until this morning when I did a jre update.

I now have Java 7 Upd 51 installed and I'm finding that I can't the client to start once I've logged into the remote site.

The remote server's admins are telling me to install the latest Citrix Receiver but I'm finding that IE still insists on using the Java client.

Is there a way to force IE not do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java client is generally a fall back option. But the setting can be defaulted at the WebUI in advanced options.

Or client deployment options in newer WebUIs.
[image]

Comment: Can you add some screen shots to show where the options are please?